# failed Jboss6.3 launch

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss6.x

This is the difficulty that i run into when i tried to launch Jboss6.3 with maven project deployment , whereas the launch was OK without deployment of project. Besides,the project deployed and launched OK on Tomcat7.x.

the message returned is like:

```
Failed to enable apledi.war.

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "apledi.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"apledi.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"apledi.war\".DEPENDENCIES: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"apledi.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have different deployment units, but you didn't specify a deployment `unitName` on your `@PersistenceContext`. So check, if all your entity managers are annotated properly, example:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "yourUnitName")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Thank you, Bevor , for the answer. The problem was found out to result from the directory on which there is space.